# Test for normability of a metric on a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

If d is a metric on a (finite dimensional) Banach Space and there exist norms $\|-\|_1$ and $\|-\|_2$ and constants $C_1,C_2 \in [1,\infty)$ satisfying:

\begin{equation}
C_1\|x-y\|_1 \leq d(x,y) \leq C_2\|x-y\|_2,
\end{equation}
then is $d$ normable?

By normable I mean there exists some norm $\|\cdot \|$  such that $\|x,y\|=d(x,y)$.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by normable?

Comment: Presumably expressible as a norm? It would need to be translation invariant, at least. I don't have my Rudin handy at the moment.

Comment: Yes, by normable I mean there exists some norm $\|\|$ such that $\|x,y\|=d(x,y)$.

Comment: The metric $d$ defines the same topology as any norm on the Banach space $X$, but if $d$ is not translation-invariant, then there does not exist a norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ such that $\left\|x-y\right\|=d(x,y)$.

Comment: ok, but how does that play a role in our (dis)proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: since all norms on a finite-dimensional space are comparable, the condition could be simpler stated as 
$$
C_1\|x-y\| \leq d(x,y) \leq C_2\|x-y\| 
$$ 
where $\|\cdot \|$ is a norm of our choice, e.g., Euclidean.

Second: the answer is negative, for example 
$$d(x,y) = |x-y|+\min(|x-y|,1)$$
is a translation-invariant metric on $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies 
$$|x-y|\le d(x,y)\le 2|x-y|$$
but is not given by any norm.

Comment: It might be helpful to mention that $d$ is not given by a norm since $d$ fails the homogeneity condition.